# What are the risks of in-person private currency exchanging for travellers?

Tags: transactions, exchanges, travel

[This answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3885/516) suggests popularity growth of people privately exchanging bitcoins for a physical currency, in person. This might occur in "coffee shops, hotels, hostels, hackerspaces, etc".

An example would be 2 travellers meeting in a hostel in, say, the UK. Traveller A has just been to the USA and traveller B is about to go there. Traveller A has US$200 that's no longer needed, so he agrees to exchange it for some of traveller B's bitcoins.

Definitely assume traveller B has a mobile phone or other internet access to perform the transfer, but please consider both cases of traveller A having and not having similar access at the time.

What are the risks of such a deal, and what can be done to improve the chances of a successful deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that "personal safety risks" are outside the scope of this website, so I'll mention the technical risk - double spend. If you don't wait for one confirmation, a double spent attack can be performed, and you won't get your Bitcoins.

Luckily, you'll only have to wait <s>five</s> ten minutes on average for a block to be found <s>(blocks are one every ten minutes, so the expected delay until the next block is five minutes)</s>.

After one confirmation, it's very unlikely such a small transaction will be double spent. If you want to increase your security, wait another block or two.

Traveller A doesn't need to have internet, he can use a [Pimpcoin](https://pimpcoin.com/)-like card (link NSFW), with SMS notifications of incoming transactions.

Comment: I think the expected time until the next block is always 10 minutes, not 5.  Are you thinking that the last block is probably 5 minutes ago, so we're "half way to finding the next one"?  It doesn't work like that.  Also, I think we were meant to also consider the case where A doesn't have a phone so won't get the SMS.

Comment: @ChrisMoore: Right, it's definitely 10 minutes. Block finding time is a memoryless distribution.

Comment: PS it's very unlikely that a small transaction will be double-spent even after 0 confirmations.

Comment: Right @ChrisMoore, my bad.

Comment: Also, without any internet or SMS, you can't really reliably accept Bitcoin ... they could always be fake, in whatever form they're received. You can't rely on the other party's computer - he can show you a fake BlockExplorer.info clone on his computer that lists the transaction as "confirmed", even though he never broadcast it.

Comment: I made a separate question about the expected time between blocks, which led to an interesting discussion.  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3909/659

Answer (score 4):

There are capital controls and anti-money laundering laws that are different for each country.  The tourist might want to become aware of what the laws are.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @ripper234's comment "he can show you a fake BlockExplorer.info clone on his computer that lists the transaction as "confirmed", even though he never broadcast it. ", it's also a possibility that any other **software or websites viewed on someone's computer might be faked**. This could include the Bitcoin Client itself (even if it looks like it's working). This is a risk for Traveller A for the situation described in the question.

Additionally, **assume that any details entered into someone's device are being logged**, so don't enter passwords or personal details that you don't want to share.

Traveller A really needs to have some kind device of their own they can use to confirm that the transaction is genuine.